# Better approach for too many if else statement

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, math

```
if ( x < 275 && x >= 0 ) 
   f = 275
else if ( x < 450 && x >= 275) (right side comparison always previous left side default comparison value
   f = 450
else if ( x < 700 && x >= 450) 
   f = 700
else if ( x < 1000 && x >= 700) 
   f = 1000
..... and more
```

is there any way or mathematical formula approach to eliminate this multiple if else statement for less code require?

Comment: I personally would drop the `&& x >= 275)` etc as they have no effect. If the list of `else if`s are too long, I'd look at using a table lookup. (BTW, please tag the question with your programming language)

Comment: Is your priority to make it run as fast as possible or to be as easy to read as possible?

Comment: @KenY-N okay, i do agree with your drop && x >= 275) would help alot. will edit the question again.

Comment: @samgak to eliminate modification in future such as adding new if else statement ( also easy to read ). I am thinking to use recurring method to solve. performance speed is not in top priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something in C (but easy enough to port to almost anything). It misses a couple of conditions (x < 0 and x > "biggest known") It doesn't add much value when you only have 4 values, but the more values you have, the more code this removes. Note that it will slow things down, but doubtful that you'd notice it unless you had a huge list of possible values.

```
int getF(int x)
{
    /* possibleValues must be sorted in ascending order */
    int possibleValues[] = { 275, 450, 700, 1000 };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(possibleValues) / sizeof(possibleValues[0]); i++)
    {
        int pv = possibleValues[i];
        if (x < pv)
        {
            return pv;
        }
    }
    /* fall thru "error" handle as you see fit */
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(x>0)
{
    if(x<275)
        f = 275;
    else if(x<450)
        f = 450;
    else if(x<700)
        f = 700;
    else if(x<1000)
        f = 1000;
    else //and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `x>0`. Just avoiding `if-else`, this also shall suffice the conditions -

```
x<275 ? 275 : (x<450 ? 450 : (x<700 ? 700 : (x<1000 ? 1000 :
```

Though if there is any defined type range of inputs like INT, BIG etc instead of 275, 450.. you can check the type of input. Also you can so the same using iteration as suggested by @John3136.